# How to get applied coupon code in observer Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, coupon, coupon-codes

I want to add a product to cart when a coupon is applied. I created an observer on event `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost`. But I don't get the applied coupon code in observer.

Can anyone tell me how to get it? Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `execute()` method of your observer you can call the following code to get the coupon code:

```
$controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
$couponCode = $controller->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code');
```